# How to avoid Out of Memory when Parsing a file into a stream in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and you like to understand why the following code results
in a `GC overhead limit exceeded` and what should be done to avoid it.

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.annotation.tailrec

  def getItems(file: Source): Stream[String] = {
    @tailrec
    def acc(it: Iterator[String],
            item: String,
            items: Stream[String]): Stream[String] = {

      if(it.hasNext){
        val line = it.next
        line take 1 match {
          case " " =>
            acc(it, item + "\n" + line, items)
          case "1" =>
            acc(it, item, Stream.cons(item, items))
        }
      }
      else {
        Stream.cons(item, items)
      }
    }
    acc(file.getLines(), "", Stream.Empty)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons of you code maybe will cause **OOM**:

1. `item` will recursively add with the file length, this maybe will very large depend on your file size.
2. For your `Stream` is repeatedly appending the accumlated `item` to `Stream`, this also maybe will very large,that cause **OOM**.

There is a way maybe can save this scenario by using **lazy evaluation** and `Stream` without `memorization`.

Comment: thank you. both 1 and 2 are valid points. I did not realize that the values in a stream are cached. My best bet is to replace the Stream by an Iterator

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to figure out what you are actually trying to do but the problem is that you are recursing with your acc function until your input file has not more elements. Here is a very simple example that converts your iterator into a stream.

```
def convert[T]( iter : Iterator[T] ) : Stream[T] = 
  if ( iter.hasNext ) {
    Stream.cons( iter.next, convert( iter ) )
  } else {
    Stream.empty
  }
```

In addition you are appending all lines that start with a space to `item`. I don't know how many such lines you have in your input but if all lines would be starting with space, you would use `(n^2)/2` characters if your input file has n characters. But I don't think that's why your recursion fails.

Answer (score 0):

`Stream` in scala is a leaky abstraction actually. It pretends to be a `Seq` but you can't use it as a regular collection if a stream is huge.
Here is an article about streams http://blog.dmitryleskov.com/programming/scala/stream-hygiene-i-avoiding-memory-leaks/
In your case the rule 'don't store Streams in method arguments' is violated (`items`).